# Java using scanner with try-with-resources

Tags: java, try-catch, try-with-resources

I have two versions of Java code that gets user input until user types "q"
Version 1:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "";
        while (!input.equals("q")) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Input was: " + input);
        }
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "";
        while (!input.equals("q")) {
            try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){
                System.out.print("Input: ");
                input = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Input was: " + input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Version 1 works as expected but version 2 does not work as expected.
That is after reading user input for the first time, it produces an error

```
Input: 12
Input was: 12Exception in thread "main" 
Input: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at RealEstateCompany.main(RealEstateCompany.java:115)
```

My guess is since version 2 uses try with resource so it closes the scanner after being used and that is causing an error?

Thank you for your help in advance!

[Update]
Version 3:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "";
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){
            while (!input.equals("q")) {
                System.out.print("Input: ");
                input = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Input was: " + input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Version 3 works. However, why version 3 is ok and version 2 is not ok?

Comment: `try-with` automatically closes the underlying `Scanner`, which automatically closes the underlying stream, which is `System.in`. After that, you're not able to get any user input anymore.

Comment: Did you try keeping try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) out of while loop?

Comment: @RajuSharma Thank you for your advice. Yes, it solved my issue, but why does this solve the problem?

Comment: Version 3 works, because when you enter the `while` loop, you're still inside the `try` block. The resource gets closed only when you leave `try`, which is what happened in your second example after one iteration.

Comment: @QBrute Thank you for your answer! I am fairly new to Java, so can you give me a little more detail?

Comment: @QBrute so in version 2 of this line try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) does not create Scanner instance because it is closed in first iteration?

Comment: @ksn added more information as answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Adding a little bit more detail to my comments*

A `try-with` block is defined as follows:

```
try(...) {
   ...
}
```

where the argument in parenthesis needs to be an instance of [`java.lang.AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). An example is the class [`java.io.InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), which is also the class for `System.in`.

A `try-with` attempts to automatically close its provided resource, once the block is left. Depending on the used resource, it closes *all its* own child resources as well.

Taking your example, you have `try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in))`, which uses `Scanner` as resource. The scanner itself uses `System.in` as resource. Once the `try` block is left (when `}` is reached) it tries to close its resources, which is the `Scanner` instance. This instance also tries to close *its* resource, the `System.in`.

Once `System.in` is closed, you can't get any input from the console anymore (at least not with some additional work, I think...).

Concretely, in your second example:

```
while (!input.equals("q")) {
    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){
            ...
    }  // <--- The block is left, scanner is closed, System.in is closed
} // <-- start a new iteration
```

Here after just one iteration, `System.in` gets closed. Sure, you create a new `Scanner` in the next iteration, but `System.in` **remains closed**, that's why you get your exception in this case.

Your third example:

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){
    while (!input.equals("q")) {
        ...
    } // <-- start a new iteration, while still in the same try block
} // <-- only after the while, your resources are closed
```

Here you're looping your `while`, while *still being inside* `try`. So no resource gets closed, until you leave `while` and `try`. That means, the one `Scanner` remains intact and with it the one `System.in`. This allows you to keep reading from the console until you're done looping.

Comment: Thank you so much for the most clear explanation. Now I feel much better about using try-with-resources!

Comment: Hi @QBrute, For the First time when Scanner object is created it opened System.in but when Scanner object is created again expectation is that it should open System.in again. Why it is not doing that?

Comment: @NeoRavi No, `System.in` is not opened by the scanner but by the JVM *once* when you run the program. Hence, there's no way to "reopen" the stream once you've closed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   String input = "";
   try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
       while (!input.equals("q")) {
           System.out.print("Input: ");
           input = scanner.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Input was: " + input);
       }
   }
```

You can use every class thats implements `Closeable` or `AutoCloseable` in try-with-resources, When code reaches the end of the try call, It call `close()` function of the `Scanner` class in our example.

Comment: Is this not basically version 3 in OPs post?

Comment: @Gal Thank you for your answer and explanation. Only thing that I do not understand now is that why version 2 does not work. I understood that at the end of try close() is called and scanner is closed but in the second iteration, in try(Scanner scanner = new ...) it recreates the new scanner instance so I think it should be able to read input one more time.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer does not answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

i run some tests and add the catch block into your code.here's the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "";
    while (!input.equals("q")) {
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Input was: " + input);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }
}
```

when add the catch block，there are 2 kinds of results
1,only inputs q, works as expected
2,inputs any other String, exception

```
Input: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at rews.pub.Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

when added the catch block, we will see that the program won't stop, because of the while loop

here is another easier test

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("inout--1---");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();

    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("inout--2---");
    input = scanner2.nextLine();
    scanner2.close();

}
```

}

and it goes same exception

```
inout--1---
11
inout--2---
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line  found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at rews.pub.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

here's my opinion.
in the end of first run, try()block will close the resource which is in the block, means we close the system.in
system.in is a object of inputSteam，and system.in is final and static, we can't open it again like 'new Scanner(System.in)'