# Recreating Scanner in Java

Tags: java, console

I'm writing a game in java, and I have a method that asks user to input the value from Console:

```
public String getUserInput() {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        return s;
    }
}
```

The thing is I want to invoke this method various number of times depends on external parameters and I never know in advance, will I invoke again or not.

But when I invoke methods like this for the second call - I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

Problems:

- I dont understand the root cause of this error: I know I can not
  reopen the scanner, but here I dont reopen it but I recreate it.
- How can I deal with it?

Comment: Look at this post which give you a description why you get that error: [using scanner with try-with-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588704/java-using-scanner-with-try-with-resources/47588812#answer-47589097)

Answer (score 5):

Don't reopen or recreate it. Use one `Scanner` for the duration of your program.

Closing a `Scanner` (as in this case, with your `try-with-resources` block) will close its input, in this case `System.in`. You don't want to close that, since you can't reopen it.

Comment: Yes, but when to close it? Should I close it manually in the end of the program? But what if my program with endup with exception, in that case Scanner will not be closed

Comment: Yes, you should close it manually at the end. If your program finishes abnormally, the `Scanner` will be gone too. It won't keep living once your program is gone.

Comment: No, (I wouldn't recommend) closing the scanner (in this case) ever, as it will close `System.in` as well, which you really don't want to do.  Let the JVM handle it